# Sentencias IF Dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Pasa lo siguiente estoy realizando un documento en Dompdf pero necesito un par de if para mostrar una información de acuerdo a la variable, con uno no tengo problema por que lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
$variable = ($Tipo_persona=="NATURAL" ?" <td width='100' rowspan='1'>
       <p align='center' class='fuente'><font size=8.9><b>PERSONA NATURAL <img src='../images/x.png' class='siono'></p>
       </td>
       <td width='100' rowspan='1'>
       <p align='center' class='fuente'><font size=8.9><b>PERSONA JURIDICA <img src='../images/rectangulo.png' class='siono'></p>
       </td>":"
```

Teniendo `:` como `else` pero ahí es donde comienza el problema porque no sé cómo colocar otro `if` o un `elseif`. Busqué el problema pero la solución que encontré es de varias versiones atrás de la librería.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo estas utilizando un operador condicional ternario el `?:`. Si lo que necesitas es meter un elseif usándolo, puedes anidarlos de la siguiente forma.

```
condicion1 ? resultado A : condicion2 ? resultado  B : resultado C;
```

Esto sería igual a:

```
if(condicion1){
     resultado A
 }elseif(condicion2){
     resultado B
 }else{
     resultado C
 }
```

Espero que te sirva. En caso contrario ¿podrías mostrar más código o definir mejor cual es exactamente el problema?

Un saludo!

Comment: Muchas Gracias no pense que fuera tan facil aunque tuve unos problemas pero ya lo tengo